# How can I download Bath 800 dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, image-segmentation

how I can find valid link for download BATH800 dataset?

"This dataset is a collection of eye images"

I tried to find the download link through the references given in different articles.
But these links have problems and do not work.

Comment: I am not aware of the BATH800 dataset. There are many collections of eye images available though. (i.e., https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kayvanshah/eye-dataset)

Comment: The dataset was used in the article I read, but the download link is broken.               [204] Bath iris database, http://www.smartsensors.co.uk/irisweb/download.htm.

Comment: What's the link to the article?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neunet.2019.07.020

Comment: From my research, the BATH Iris Dataset is no longer available: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885621000147
"the extensive BATH database reached only limited popularity mainly due to its relatively short lifespan."